# How to store data in CSV file but the data is in for loop python

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping, export-to-csv

right now I am doing web scrapping using python selenium. The [data in the web browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT9sS.png) that I want to scrap. The xpath should be looking like this `'//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr[1]/td[4]'`. On my mind I change `tr[1]` into `tr[str(x+1)]` so I able to print the each row of data by using for loop. `td[4]` because the each data is on the column number `4`. Here the [Output by using for loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhQey.png).

here the code:

```
for x in range(tableLength+1):
    text1 = '//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr['
    text2 = ']/td[4]'
    combineText = text1+str(x+1)+text2
    trx = driver.find_element_by_xpath(combineText).text
```

The problem is I did not know how the way to store all data into CSV file. Is it my data is in array or string. I try this code:

```
with open('data.csv', mode='w', newline='') as csv_file:
  csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  for row in trx:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The data that store in CSV file is `59` (which is the last data). I want it to store all of data that I had been scrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to generate a csv file from a list,
assuming that each file's row is a list element of that list.

Example:

```
rows = [['a','b','c'], ['x','y','z']]

>>> csv = ''
>>> for row in rows:
        x = ','.join(map(str,(row)))
        csv += x + '\n'

>>> print(csv)
```

Output:

```
a,b,c
x,y,z
```

Then, you just need to write this output into a file with a '.csv' extension.

You could return that as a response or whatever is needed.

Example:

```
# Return the csv file as an attachment.
return Response(
                 csv_file,
                 mimetype="text/csv",
                 headers={
                        "Content-disposition":"attachment;\
                        filename=my_file.csv"\
                 }
               )
```

Comment: Keeping a whole file in memory is highly discouraged, for a number of reasons. The same goes for returning the whole file in a plain HTTP response (use a streaming response instead)

Comment: @Pynchia I agree with you in principle. So, I more accurate solution is: "do the above if file is 'small' enough".

Answer (score 0):

Previously I put the csv inside the for loop, I just change the structure put the for loop inside csv. Such as the code below:

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as csv: 
    # directly go to Summary of Daily Transaction by Agency
    driver.get("http:<link of the current page I want to scrap>")

    # to find first date and last date of the month
    currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    firstDate = (currentDate.replace(day=1)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    
    today = datetime.datetime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day)
    nxt_mnth = today.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    lastDate = (nxt_mnth - datetime.timedelta(days=nxt_mnth.day)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    # 

    # input find first date and last date of the month
    fromDate = driver.find_element_by_name("mainForm:dateFrom_input")
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(fromDate).perform()
    fromDate.send_keys(str(firstDate))
    toDate = driver.find_element_by_name("mainForm:dateTo_input")
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(toDate).perform()
    toDate.send_keys(str(lastDate))
    # 

    agencyList = ['mainForm:agency_2','mainForm:agency_12','mainForm:agency_13','mainForm:agency_14','mainForm:agency_16','mainForm:agency_17','mainForm:agency_18','mainForm:agency_19','mainForm:agency_35','mainForm:agency_36','mainForm:agency_37']
    for K in agencyList:
        dropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("mainForm:agency_label")
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(dropdown).perform()

        agencyName = (driver.find_element_by_id(K).text).replace(',', ';')

        selectAgency = driver.find_element_by_id(K)
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(selectAgency).perform()

        searchBtn = driver.find_element_by_id("mainForm:j_idt128")
        webdriver.ActionChains(driver).click(searchBtn).perform()
        # code end here

        # page usually output 10 data I want to output all 30 data
        selectDropdown = driver.find_element_by_id("mainForm:j_idt130_rppDD")
        all_options = selectDropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        for option in all_options:
            option.click()
        #
        sleep(2)
        # to find length of rows table data
        rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr')
        tableLength = (len(rows))
        #
        
        csv.write(agencyName+ "\n")
    
        for x in range(tableLength):
            
            trx1 = '//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr['
            trxTd = ']/td[4]'
            date1 = '//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr['
            dateTd = ']/td[2]'
            agencyTd = ']/td[3]'
            agency1 = '//*[@id="mainForm:j_idt130_data"]/tr['
            combineTrx = trx1+str(x+1)+trxTd
            combineDate = date1+str(x+1)+dateTd
            combineAgency = agency1+str(x+1)+agencyTd
            try:
                trx = (driver.find_element_by_xpath(combineTrx).text).replace(',', '') 
                date = (driver.find_element_by_xpath(combineDate).text)
                agency = (driver.find_element_by_xpath(combineAgency).text)

                print(trx)
                csv.write(date+","+agency+","+trx + "\n")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                break #if there no data it will continue go to next agency
        csv.write("\n")
```

Instead of this structure

```
for (){
    with open () as csv:
         csv.write
}
```

You should do this structure in order to store each data into CSV file using for loop

```
with open () as csv:
      for (){
          csv.write
       }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).